# Как сделать так, чтобы активный элемент меню подсвечивался?

Tags: javascript, html, css

меня есть секция .services в которой есть меню sidebar-menu. Как сделать так, чтобы пункт на который я нажал горел белым цветом и вписать это уже в существующий JS код? Пытался в JS коде просто задать добавление css свойства цвета, но в итоге загораются все пункты

Сам сайт http://ct03638.tmweb.ru/

Весь код jsfiddle.net/p7ubnje6/

Сам JS код

```js
 $('.sidebar-menu li ').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var index_ = $(this).closest("li").index()
        $('.sidebar-menu li').removeClass('big');
        $(".sidebar-menu li:eq(" + index_ + ")").addClass('big');
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так должно работать:

```
$('.sidebar-menu li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sidebar-menu li').removeClass('big');
    $(this).addClass('big');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу :

С помощью кода выше добавляется класс big к элементу li 
Цвет нужно прописать элементу а

Ваш css должен выглядеть вот так и все заработает:

```
li.big a{
    color: #fff;
}

.big {
    transform: scale(1.3) translateX(10%);
}
```